# How to migrate only TOP 1000 rows from Oracle to SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssms

I'm trying to migrate only a limited number of rows from several tables in Oracle to SQL Server. I have SQL Server Management Studio and SSMA for Oracle installed, but I'm not sure how to selectively import data into a new SQL Server database. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: do you know how to create views?

Answer (score 2):

The workflow I would probably use:

1. On old server, create a new table for migration purposes
2. Populate migration table with data from old table: `INSERT INTO migration_table (<fields>) SELECT <columns> FROM old_table ORDER BY <priority> LIMIT 0,1000;`
3. Migrate migration table using admin tools
4. rename migration table to the proper name you want.